# Name of this design pattern? A little like Strategy and Chain of Resp

Tags: design-patterns

Does anyone know if this pattern has a name? I tend to use it a fair amount.

Basically it is a behavioral pattern that allows you provide a method with an enumerable of classes that implement an interface, and it runs all of them. Here is a C# example:

```
interface IInputValidator
{
    bool IsValid(int input);
}

class GreaterThanZeroValidator : IInputValidator
{
    public bool IsValid(int input)
    {
        return input > 0;
    }
}

class LessThanOneThousandValidator : IInputValidator
{
    public bool IsValid(int input)
    {
        return input < 1000;
    }
}
```

then the method that uses these:

```
public void ValidateInput(int input, IEnumerable<IInputValidator> validators)
{
    bool allValid = true;
    foreach(var validator in validators)
    {
        if(!validator.IsValid(input))
            allValid = false;
    }

    if(!allValid)
        throw new ArgumentException();
}
```

So to me it looks a lot like a Strategy pattern, but with multiple strategies that all get a chance to handle the input, whereas the normal Strat pattern just takes in 1 strategy.

It is also a little like a Chain of Responsibility, except that in a normal CoR, the handlers are only iterated deep enough to find the 1 that can handle the input, and each responsibility has a reference to the next responsibility (like a linked list), whereas in my example, I pass them all in together.

I'm just looking to put a name to this thing. Thanks for any help!

Answer (score 1):

IMHO this is Chain-Of-Responsibility. The reason is that the LINQ `All` extension terminates the moment it reaches the first item that causes the predicate to return false.

Here's LINQPad code to prove my claim about `All`:

```
void Main()
{
    try
    {
        Console.WriteLine("all items are 2?");
        Console.WriteLine(YieldOneThenThrow().All(i => i == 2));
        Console.WriteLine("all items are 1?");
        Console.WriteLine(YieldOneThenThrow().All(i => i == 1));
    }
    catch (NotSupportedException)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("exception! second item was visited.");
    }
}

IEnumerable<int> YieldOneThenThrow()
{
    yield return 1;
    throw new NotSupportedException();
}
```

...and the output:

> all items are 2?
>   False
>   all items are 1?
>   exception! second item was visited.

Comment: Good point. I used Linq to make the sample code shorter. I'm going to edit my code to do a full `foreach` for all the items. Sorry!

Comment: @rally25rs - no problem. :) I do a lot of UI work and this item hits home. One of the things I hate as a user is when a page only notifies me of only the first invalid item rather than all of the things I need to fix. So see the utility in a "collect all issues" pattern even if that's just one use of this.

Comment: Yep, the 2 places I usually use it are to "collect all validation issues" or to "run all these business rules".

Answer (score 0):

But yeah, the strategy pattern is designed, and the consumption is chain of responsibility.

It depends on what the user will get - If the user is provided ValidateInput I'll class it as CoR. If the user is given the first set of classes only, then I'd call it Strategy.